# Eclipse Luna - Project explorer is empty after importing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I am importing or trying to create project in eclipse Luna I am getting the following error:

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Java
>   Builder' on project 'project-name'. loader constraint violation:
>   loader (instance of
>   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) previously
>   initiated loading for a different type with name
>   "org/aspectj/runtime/internal/CFlowCounter" Errors running builder
>   'Maven Project Builder' on project 'project-name'. loader
>   constraint violation: when resolving method
>   "scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.jcompiler.BuildManagerAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_jcompiler_BuildManagerAspect$1$add4995(Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/events/BuildManager;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Lorg/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure;)Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IResourceDelta;"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current
>   class, org/eclipse/core/internal/events/BuildManager, and the class
>   loader (instance of
>   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for resolved
>   class,
>   scala/tools/eclipse/contribution/weaving/jdt/jcompiler/BuildManagerAspect,
>   have different Class objects for the type
>   .weaving.jdt.jcompiler.BuildManagerAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_jcompiler_BuildManagerAspect$1$add4995(Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/events/BuildManager;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Lorg/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure;)Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IResourceDelta;
>   used in the signature Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project
>   'test'. org/aspectj/runtime/internal/CFlowCounter Errors running
>   builder 'Validation' on project 'test'. loader constraint violation:
>   when resolving method
>   "scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.jcompiler.BuildManagerAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_jcompiler_BuildManagerAspect$1$add4995(Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/events/BuildManager;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Lorg/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure;)Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IResourceDelta;"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current
>   class, org/eclipse/core/internal/events/BuildManager, and the class
>   loader (instance of
>   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for resolved
>   class,
>   scala/tools/eclipse/contribution/weaving/jdt/jcompiler/BuildManagerAspect,
>   have different Class objects for the type
>   .weaving.jdt.jcompiler.BuildManagerAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_jcompiler_BuildManagerAspect$1$add4995(Lorg/eclipse/core/internal/events/BuildManager;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Lorg/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure;)Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IResourceDelta;
>   used in the signature

I've checked the permissions, and restarted eclipse, but nothing helped me.

Do someone know/met this error? how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, just want to make sure, are you trying to open a scala project as java project? could tell us more about the imported project?

Comment: No, its a simple java project. and it crashes also when trying to build a new one. I don't know why its trying to use scala tools.

Comment: Looking at the 'Builders' page of the project Properties might show something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. Thanks to @kucing_terbang comment, I got to understand the source of problem is

> . loader constraint violation: when resolving method
>   "scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.jcompiler...

I've tried to install scala IDE, and the scala tools were avoiding any activty.

I simply removed the scala tools (help > installationDetails, uninstall)
Create a new workspace, and the import got to work!